# Extracting elements from a varchar column in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

I have a sample data, as shown below;

| NAME | Values | Typeof(Values) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BNL | [1,2] | VARCHAR |

As seen the data type is VARCHAR for the second column.

**Expected Output**

| Name | Values |
| --- | --- |
| BNL | 1 |
| BNL | 2 |

In a way, we want to split the row into two rows depending on how many elements we have in the `Values` column. I was looking into FLATTEN as an option;

```
select temp.*,
         t.value
     from temp,
     table(flatten(temp.values)) as t;
```

But since it is a VARCHAR, we get following error message;

`invalid type [VARCHAR(16777216)] for parameter '1'`

Can I please get some help here?thanx

Comment: you can also use `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [TRY_PARSE_JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_parse_json.html):

```
select temp.*,
     t.value
 from temp,
 table(flatten(TRY_PARSE_JSON(temp.values))) as t;
```